# Entity Framework Core 5: configuring many to many relationships, how to specify foreign key names

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a a existing SQL Server database with many to many relationship `Books` <-> `Authors` implemented via join table `Publications`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Books]
(
    [BookId] INT IDENTITY,
    [Title] NVARCHAR(160) NOT NULL,
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Authors]
(
    [AuthorId] INT IDENTITY,
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Publications]
(
    [BookId] INT NOT NULL,
    [AuthorId] INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Publication] PRIMARY KEY ([BookId], [AuthorId])
)
```

I need to configuring a many to many relation ship in Entity Framework Core 5.

With EF 6, it is fairly simple:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Entity<Author>() // an Author
         .HasMany(a => a.Books) // has many Books
         .WithMany(b => b.Authors) // with many Authors
         .Map(mc =>
               {
                    mc.ToTable("Publications"); // Join table: Publications
                    mc.MapLeftKey("AuthorId"); // FK Author: AuthorId
                    mc.MapRightKey("BookId"); // FK Book : BookId
               });
}
```

But I have problems with Entity Framework Core 5:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Entity<Author>() // an Author
          .HasMany(a => a.Books) // has many Books
          .WithMany(b => b.Authors) // with many Authors
          .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("Publications")); // join table: Publications
          // how to define foreign key columns?
}
```

I don't know how to map the foreign key columns. EF Core 5 use the pattern `AuthorsAuthorId` and `BooksBookId`.

How can I change this naming convention?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this if the many to many table is not relevant within the C# code:

```
public class Author
{
   public int AuthorId { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
public class Book
{
   public int BookId { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
public class Db : DbContext
{
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
   {
      mb.Entity<Author>() // an Author
      .HasMany(a => a.Books) // has many Books
      .WithMany(b => b.Authors) // with many Authors
      .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>("Publications",
        x => x.HasOne<Book>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(nameof(Book.BookId)),
        y => y.HasOne<Author>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(nameof(Author.AuthorId)),
        z => z.ToTable("Publications"));
   }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped. Can you please mark my answer as complete? Thanks

Comment: I want to upvote this answer but it uses terrible naming to explain the finer points. What are `x`, `y`, and `z` in these cases? Don't use single letter names expecting people to just magically figure what they really are.

Comment: David, yes thanks you are correct on the naming x and y should be renamed. Though stating "expecting people to just magically figure what they really are", would be better phrased as "please rename, so the intention is clear", sure you'll agree there's little merit in condescending. We are here to help each other :-) Thanks